# php soap setting type

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I am trying to create the following element in my soup call

```
<Item xsi:type="Service">
    <ID>9910</ID>
</Item>
```

I have the following php code

```
class Service {
    private $ID;

    public function __construct($ID){
        $this->ID = $ID;
    }
}

$service = new Service(9910);
$param['Item'] = $service;

$soapItem->client->SoapFunction($param);
```

The XML that I am generating is

```
<Item/>
```

Obviously there are numerous other items in this soap call that are being formed correctly.  This is the only item that is type cast.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this typo in your code?  `$param[Item'] = $service;`?  Note missing quote at beginning of key name.

Comment: yes typo sorry fixing it now

Comment: Was that a problem in your code?

Comment: No code was correct typo was just on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got the result I wanted

```
class Service {
    private $ID;

    public function __construct($ID){
        $this->ID = $ID;
    }
}

$service = new Service(9910);
$param['Item'] =  new SoapVar($service, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'Service', 'http://name.space.com/');

$soapItem->client->SoapFunction($param);
```